# Default Nginx set up in Laravel public folder

Tags: laravel, nginx, nginx-config

I had the default .htaccess set up for my Laravel app in /public folder (https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/9.x/public/.htaccess):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Send Requests To Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Now I've migrated to a new server environment with Nginx. I have managed to direct the requests to this /public directory, however I do not know how to replicate the working of this .htaccess on the new Nginx server, so the application works partially. For example calls to my api don't work (api.mysite.com)

**UPDATE**

OLD SET UP - APACHE SERVER

**.htaccess in /wwwroot:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

# BACKOFFICE API
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Host} ^(?:api\.mysite\.com)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*) public/$1 [NC,L,NS]


# FRONTEND API
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Host} ^(?:src\.mysite\.com)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*) public/$1 [NC,L,NS]

# ANYOTHER TO DIST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dist
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /dist/$1 [L]
```

**.htaccess in /wwwroot/public was default Laravel .htaccess, the first one above.**

NEW SET UP - NGINX (@van-Shatsky, I followed your advice in [Nginx dynamic root from subdomain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72683250/nginx-dynamic-root-from-subdomain/72683840#72683840))

```
map $http_host $webroot {
    src.mysite.com  /home/site/wwwroot/public;
    api.mysite.com  /home/site/wwwroot/public;
    default           /home/site/wwwroot/dist;
}

server {
    #proxy_cache cache;
    #proxy_cache_valid 200 1s;
    listen 8080;
    listen [::]:8080;
    
    server_name *.mysite.com;
    
    
    root $webroot;
    
    index  index.php index.html;

}
```

With this configuration in Nginx, requests addressed to /dist (front-end application) are served correctly, but requests to api.mysite.com or src.mysite.com do not work. I hope I have clarified it.

Comment: PD: my root file in /wwwroot/public is index.php and my root file in /wwwroot/dist is index.html

Answer (score 1):

This particular apache config could be rewritten for nginx the following way, for example:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @maybe_rewrite;
}
location @maybe_rewrite {
    # if we are here, $uri is not a physical file or directory
    rewrite (.+)/$ $1 permanent;
    # if previous rewrite rule isn't triggered, rewrite request to index.php
    rewrite ^ /index.php last;
}
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param HTTP_AUTHORIZATION $http_authorization if_not_empty;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$uri;
    fastcgi_pass ...
}
```

However I don't know what are you meaning by "api calls not working" and how your current nginx config looks, so you'd better add your full nginx config to your question.

Comment: Edited. All my best Ivan.

Comment: Things are becoming clearer. One more question, is there any `.htaccess` in the `dist` folder? What is there? Some kind of React/Angular/Vue/etc JS-framework based web app?